# MAX7219 Arduino cascade issue

Tags: arduino

I have 6 daisy chained MAX7219 connected to an arduino nano.
The issue is that all of them work fine once but the data of only first two MAX7219 is retained, the remaining seven segment displays go blank.

Arduino code-

```
 #include <MAX72XX.h>
 #include<SoftwareSerial.h>
 #include "LedControl.h"
int a=1111;
int b=2222;
int c=3333;
int d=4444;
int e=5555;
int f=6666;



LedControl lc=LedControl(12,11,10,6);//(datain,clk,load)
unsigned long delaytime=250;
void setup() {


  for(int address=0;address<6;address++) {
         lc.shutdown(address,false);
/* Set the brightness to a medium values */
lc.setIntensity(address,7);
/* and clear the display */
lc.clearDisplay(address);
  }
}


void loop() { 
printNumber(a);
delay(250);
printNumber1(b);
delay(250); 
printNumber2(c);
delay(250);
printNumber3(d);
delay(250);
printNumber4(e);
delay(250);
printNumber5(f);
delay(250);
}

void printNumber(int v) {  
   int ones;  
    int tens;  
   int hundreds; 
    int thousands;  
  ones=v%10;  
  v=v/10;  
  tens=v%10;  
  v=v/10;
   hundreds=v%10;
   v=v/10;
    thousands=v;   
  lc.setDigit(0,0,(byte)thousands,false); 
  lc.setDigit(0,1,(byte)hundreds,false);
  lc.setDigit(0,2,(byte)tens,false); 
  lc.setDigit(0,3,(byte)ones,false); 

}
```

Similar print functions for the rest of the displays.

[image: Setup image]

Comment: Could be a hardware problem, but we have nothing to check that.

Comment: Have you added the required 100 nF and 10uF capacitors to each 7129 (close to the chips VCC and GND pins)?